# Can I Implement a Well-Trusted Protocol with Well-Trusted Libraries in JavaScript securely?

Tags: protocol-design, protocol-analysis

Just for anyone reading this: **DO NOT ROLL YOUR OWN ALGORITHM.**

Besides that, is implementing a well-trusted protocol with well-trusted algorithms and libraries a good idea? Is this likely to colossally fail like rolling your own crypto? Could this be used in production after enough peer review? (I know that rolling your own crypto is definitely NOT secure)

Let's say I'm trying to implement a simple JavaScript website that generates RSA key pairs, RSA encrypts, and signs, and also AES encrypts data (e.g. an asymmetric key exchange than a symmetric conversation; the simplest protocol out there). If I use well-respected libraries, respected algorithms (i.e. AES & RSA) and peer-review the website, is this likely to have vulnerabilities?

(We're ignoring all the issues of authenticity in code with JavaScript) (Also, I'm not implementing my own algorithm, i.e. AES, to keep that clear)

Comment: There many libraries over there and they have some known problems, etc and waiting for your help! This is a good way to learn.

Comment: A trustworthy protocol is relatively easy to identify. (Which isn't to say that it's at all hard to make incorrect judgements on protocols based on limited knowledge.) Finding trustworthy implementations probably won't be easy for JavaScript.

Comment: @FutureSecurity how can I know if I have found a trustworthy implementation? Should I look for an implementation with the most scrutiny?

Comment: JavaScript is notorious for its messiness and ubiquitous use of vulnerable libraries. I'm not a JS programmer primarily for those kinds of headaches. I'd recommend a binding of lib Sodium for other languages. It's not possible to use one in a browser, however. You would need a pure JS port, but I wouldn't trust a JS reimplementation.

Comment: Oh. Good. It turns out that there actually is an official JS build. (Cross compiled from the original. That avoids a lot of the danger of re-implementation. Not everything, though. Side channel attacks for example.) Someone else will know more on the topic than I do, so keep looking into things..Don't trust people just because they're confident, though. And don't trust software just because it's popular.

Comment: Alright thanks! I will definitely look for official builds more often than not. Is there any way to tell if a library has been scrutinized enough? Should I wait a certain amount of time after the library's release date to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to implement or design and implement your own protocol then using well established libraries is generally the way to do it. JavaScript is a large eco-system. For such ecosystems it is not adviced to implement your own (partial) "hazardous materials" library for the low level functionality that you require. It is much more likely that there is something out there that would be more secure.

Of course, if there already is a higher level protocol or protocol implementation out there then you should definitely try and use or improve that. Developing transport security - which is often what is tried with JavaScript - is very hard.  This is why most of the time the best solution is to use TLS underneath.

Comment: I have implemented e.g. web-security one time because it was easier to implement *and secure* my own internal product than what was already out there. But that was kind of a unique situation because I could not find *any* documentation on the web-security of Glassfish and Tomcat (Java Application Servers) and I suspected that they were broken - as they proved to be. But note that at that time I was already a seasoned secure developer and CS student.

Comment: great experience from earliest times.